# Get console output in Mercurial.Net

Tags: c#, mercurial

I am trying to do commit and push using `Mercurial.Net` library:

```
var repo = new Repository(repositoryPath);

var branchCommand = new BranchCommand { Name = branch };
repo.Branch(branchCommand);

var commitCommand = new CommitCommand { Message = commitMessage, OverrideAuthor = author };
repo.Commit(commitCommand);

var pushCommand = new PushCommand { AllowCreatingNewBranch = true, Force = true, };
repo.Push(pushCommand);
```

On `repo.Push(pushCommand)` it throws an exception `Mercurial.MercurialExecutionException` with message 'abort: Access is denied'.

The question is: Is there any way in `Mercurial.Net` to get the output of mercurial console?

Answer (score 0):

The message you're receiving appears to be a message the remote is printing. It looks like you haven't set up auth properly — or you've authenticated correctly, but on the remote side you haven't got correct access rights.